# I have to scroll down automatically if there is animation in the page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have googled out and seen somany questions in stackoverflow but any of them doesn't help me
I am having an animation as following I want to move my curser down to last displayed record.
accordingly. I have written the following code. I am geeting the required output.please help me

```
function Scrolldown() {
    window.scrollBy(0, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").animate({
        marginLeft: "0.2in"
    }, 10).first().show(150, function showNext() {
        $(this).next().show(150, showNext);
    });
});
window.onload = Scrolldown();
```

Comment: do you mean text edit cursor like in text box OR you want to animate and hover the cursor(pointer) to that record ?

Comment: I am displaying record using repeater control.I am having 25 records on page. as of my page load .displaying the record start from one and moves on. But I want page to be scroll down accordingly as the data displaying

Comment: i haven't programmed in `asp` ever but although the final output on the page is just a table with data in it so perhaps i can help you but first you have to clarify the some points:- 1. what does `I am getting the required output` in you question means ? Does this means that you are able to scroll the browser window when the table is loaded but not getting the focus to the last record?   2.is the table is loaded all at once or you are adding rows based on some event.  3.Does the rows contain editable data like `<input>` type etc.

Comment: 1)sorry for that .I am not getting required output(correction).2) No not at once I am putting a delay of 150  in between each and every record for displaying here (.first().show(150, function showNext()..) 3)no it doen't contain any editable data

Answer (score 0):

this is not the exact answer as your problem is specific not generic but it will provide you an approximate solution

you have to add following code inside the block where you are appending row to your table

```
$(window).scrollTop($(document).height()-$(window).height())
```

here is the demo of what i am trying to say http://jsfiddle.net/v8xcK/